# How can we calculate the build time of FDM (Fused Deposition Modeling)?

Tags: fdm, printer-building

I am currently working on my research project in the field of additive manufacturing, specifically focusing on estimating the build time of FDM (Fused Deposition Modeling). As part of my work, I am seeking guidance on how to calculate or estimate the build time for FDM processes.
I would like to understand the equation or methodology used to determine the build time, particularly for both a single part and decomposed parts. Additionally, I am interested in knowing how to calculate the number of decomposed parts in the build process.
If possible, I would appreciate insights into any specific factors or considerations that should be taken into account when calculating the build time, such as material properties, printer settings, or part geometry.
Any references, recommended literature, or personal experiences related to this topic would be highly valuable to my research.
Thank you in advance for your time and expertise. I look forward to learning from your insights and contributions.

Comment: You may get a better answer by approaching the company behind whichever software you are using as most of the variables used are highly customisable, and can vary considerably between the hardware that you're using.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm specifically looking for the fundamental equation or methodology to calculate the build time in FDM. Do you have any insights on this?

Comment: I think that you're question may be too involved for this forum as there are too many variables involved to easily explain. For example, the bottom and top layers are often printed slower than other layers, and the support material is printed at a different speed again. You also need to take into account travel time between different places when not printing.

Comment: Can we estimate the build time with  Build time = Number of layers x Layer time.?

Comment: Yes, but you'd first need to calculate the time for each layer, which is difficult since each layer might be very different. For example, some layers would be hollow, other would have filling material printed at a different speed. With a resin printer you just calculate the time per layer X the number of layers because every layer takes the same amount of time to print (allowing for the first few layers which take slightly longer).

Comment: Ok so there is no exact formula to estimate the build time of FDM thank you for your time

Comment: Don't forget about acceleration and deceleration... This question has been asked before, if you search for `calculate print time` at the top, you will find [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4472/how-is-the-print-time-of-an-object-to-be-printed-estimated) answered question. This can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the model you are going to print should be computationally feasible. However, the more coordinate changes you make, the longer the printing time will be. If you intend to print a detailed part with transitions between layers, for example, the more indentations it has and the variation in material density, the longer the processing time will be. The compatibility between the material used and the printer is also important. The melting temperature should be suitable for both the filament and the printer.

Answer (score 0):

The time estimation of the typical slicer operates the following way:

- First, the model is cut into layers, as demanded by the slicer.
- Each layer is solved for its perimeters, infill, and required movement between them, resulting in a very long and complex path that the print head will follow. This is by the way the longest part of slicing.
- The length of all paths is multiplied by the speed for each path type, and the times for each segment are added up. Technically, the speed needs to be a term including the 1st and 2nd derivate of the speed (acceleration and jerk), as well as the set max speed, but in older programs, those are often skipped, resulting in a gross underestimation of print times but much faster computation.

  - These durations are added up per layer, so that the next operation can be performed properly.
- Then, if a layer has a shorter time than the minimum time, a pause is added into the code at the appropriate place, bringing that layer to the minimum duration.
- Finally, all the layer times are added up, resulting in an estimated print time.

Generally, there is no way to estimate the time for heating up the printer to running temperatures, so those times are generally not accounted for in the print time estimates either.